# search results from a Django model method including the results from earlier calls to the same method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django Model that tracks email message IDs as the message passes through different servers. It has a models.ForeignKey field to itself, so we can chain them together to follow the full path of a message through many servers.

The model has a 'get_children()' method that recursively looks for all messages descended from the given message.

```
class Relay(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    qid = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    received_from = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT
    )
    def get_children(self, parent_messages=set()):
        for r in Relay.objects.filter(received_from=self):
            r.get_children(parent_messages)
        parent_messages.add(self)
        p = list(parent_messages)
        parent_messages = set()
        return p
```

If I run a single query from the Django shell, it works as expected. "Solo" messages return only themselves. Messages with multiple child/descendant messages are found as well.

```
    >>> r = Relay.objects.get(qid='xo2')
    >>> r.get_children()
    [<Relay: server2 foo>, <Relay: server3 bbb>, <Relay: server1 xo2>]
```

If I kill and restart the shell, the next query works as expected, fetching a single message

```
    >>> r = Relay.objects.get(qid='singletonMsg')
    >>> r.get_children()
    [<Relay: server5 singletonMsg>]
```

But if I run get_children() repeatedly within a single Django shell session, it always includes the results of the previous get_children() calls.

```
    >>> r = Relay.objects.get(qid='singletonMsg')
    >>> r.get_children()
    # expected result
    [<Relay: server5 singletonMsg>]  
    >>>
    >>> r = Relay.objects.get(qid='xo2')
    >>> r.get_children()
    # unexpected result - should not include singletonMsg 
    [<Relay: server2 foo>, <Relay: server3 bbb>, <Relay: server5 singletonMsg>, <Relay: server1 xo2>]
    >>>
    >>> r = Relay.objects.get(qid='singletonMsg')
    >>> r.get_children()
    # unexected result - should just return singletonMsg ??
    [<Relay: server2 foo>, <Relay: server3 bbb>, <Relay: server5 singletonMsg>, <Relay: server1 xo2>]
```

I was originally returning the "parent_messages" set from the function. I tried 
    return [m for m in parent_messages]
and the current list() thinking it was a closure issue, but no luck.
I am stumped. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the code:

```
def get_children(self, parent_messages=set()):
    ...
```

You are defining an set object in memory called `parent_messages`.  Since set objects are *mutable*, each reference to `parent_messages` actually references the same object, and each change made to `parent_messages` changes the same object in memory.  When you make an additional `get_children` call, you are still referring to the original `parent_messages` object that you defined.

See [The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) for a more in-depth explanation of this.

Now, to answer your question, I would strongly recommend using [`django-mptt`](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) (`pip install django-mptt`).  This would massively simplify the code you need to accomplish this:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel

class Relay(MPTTModel):
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    qid = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    received_from = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT
    )
```

execution:

```
>>> r = Relay.objects.get(qid='xo2')
>>> r.get_descendants()
[<Relay: server2 foo>, <Relay: server3 bbb>, <Relay: server1 xo2>]
```

`get_descendants` gets all children of r, and all of their children, and so on.  If you want to only refer to the direct children of r, use `get_children` instead.